# Drag and drop lists - multiple items with same priority

Tags: usability, website-design, web-app, lists, drag-n-drop

Initially, I had the following requirements:

1. There are 2 lists with items. The user needs to be able to move the items from one list into the other.
2. Each item needs to have a priority.

I've implemented the following solution:

[image: mock]

The user can drag and drop the items and I'm also keeping track of their priority.
For example, in List1, Item1 has priority 1 and Item2 has priority 2 and so on.
In List2, there is just Item4 with priority 1.

So this solution covers all the requirements.

The problem is that now there is a new requirement: **multiple items can have the same priority**.

So I can have Item1 and Item2 with priority 1 and Item3 with priority 2.

Can this current solution be adapted to this new requirement? I did think about it but wasn't able to find a solution.

Or is there a completely different approach that is more suitable?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the context of the list? in other words, if item 1 (P1) moves to another list w/ a P1, can you decide where you drop it and change the priority? What are the business requirements here for prioritization?

Comment: if I move item 1 (p1) to another list which has an item with p1, I should be able to specify that both items will have p1, or that the new item will have p2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists are generally used to show items sorted by a specified criteria (even if it is just based on user preferences) and can either have a value associated with the item (which is it sorted on).

However, in your case, to show items with the same order of priority requires some additional indicator to be applied to the items. An additional design problem to be solved is that if multiple items can have same priority (i.e. not just the top ranked item) then the combinations and mechanisms become much more complex, as it normally the case when you have a very flexible or generic rule to apply.

So I would suggest that you need some way to tag or apply the ranking very precisely (e.g. a dropdown or tag that you can assign to each item) if you want to be able to specify the priority and have it persist in both lists. It seems to be outside the current scope of the design and an enhancement to the components that you are using.

Alternatively, if you have a specific or specified set of items and it is just a matter of assigning priorities to all of the items, then you can create a more customized container and interactions to do this, like containers that are ranked in terms of priority and you can just drag each item into it.